# Firebird select from table distinct one field

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

The question I asked yesterday was simplified but I realize that I have to report the whole story.
I have to extract the data of 4 from 4 different tables into a Firebird 2.5 database and the following query works:

```
SELECT 
PRODUZIONE_T t.CODPRODUZIONE, 
PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA as numeroco,
    ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.RAGIONESOCIALE1, 
    PRODUZIONE_T.DATACONSEGNA, 
    PRODUZIONE_T.REVISIONE,
    ANGUTENTI.NOMINATIVO, 
    ORDINI.T_DATA,
FROM PRODUZIONE_T
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDINI_T ON PRODUZIONE_T.CODORDINE=ORDINI_T.CODORDINE 
INNER JOIN ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI ON ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.CODCLIFOR=ORDINI_T.CODCLIFOR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ANGUTENTI ON ANGUTENTI.IDUTENTE = PRODUZIONE_T.RESPONSABILEUC
ORDER BY right(numeroco,2) DESC, left(numeroco,3) desc 
rows 1 to 500;
```

However the query returns me double (or more) due to the REVISIONE column. 
How do I select only the rows of a single NUMEROCOMMESSA with the maximum REVISIONE value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce7cf/4

Sample Data (as u set it in your original question):

```
create table TAB1 (
  cod integer primary key,
  n_order varchar(10) not null,
  s_date date  not null,
  revision integer not null );

alter table tab1 add constraint UQ1 unique (n_order,revision);  

insert into TAB1 values ( 1, '001/18', '2018-02-01', 0 );
insert into TAB1 values ( 2, '002/18', '2018-01-31', 0 );
insert into TAB1 values ( 3, '002/18', '2018-01-30', 1 );
```

The query:

```
select * 
from tab1 d
join ( select n_ORDER, MAX(REVISION) as REVISION
       FROM TAB1
       Group By n_ORDER ) m
  on m.n_ORDER = d.n_ORDER and m.REVISION = d.REVISION
```

Suggestions:

1. Google and read the classic book:  "Understanding SQL" by Martin Gruber
2. Read Firebird SQL reference: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25.html

Here is yet one more solution using *Windowed Functions* introduced in Firebird 3 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce7cf/13

I do not have Firebird 3 at hand, so can not actually check if there would not be some sudden incompatibility, do it at home :-D

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT
     TAB1.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY n_order 
         ORDER BY revision DESC
      ) AS rank
   FROM TAB1
) d
WHERE rank = 1
```

Read documentation

- https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-window-functions/
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html

Which of the three (including Gordon's one) solution would be faster depends upon specific database - the real data, the existing indexes, the selectivity of indexes.

While window functions can make the join-less query, I am not sure it would be faster on real data, as it maybe can just ignore indexes on `order+revision` cortege and do the *full-scan* instead, before `rank=1` condition applied. While the first solution would most probably use indexes to get maximums without actually reading every row in the table.

The Firebird-support mailing list suggested a way to break out of the loop, to only use a single query: The trick is using both windows functions and CTE (common table expression): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce7cf/2

```
WITH TMP AS (
  SELECT 
   *,
   MAX(revision) OVER (
         PARTITION BY n_order 
       ) as max_REV
  FROM TAB1
)
SELECT * FROM TMP
WHERE revision = max_REV
```

Comment: What is _"on `order+revision` cortege"_?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel compound index on both columns. Here I mean "order+revision" as aggregation(cortege, vector) of two distinct value sets.

Comment: BTW, Mark, I tried to simplify the WinFunc query, by removing the wrapping query and moving "rank=1" condition into the inner one, either as WHERE or HAVING, and it did not work neither in MS SQL nor Postgress nor Oracle. Was it implementations limitations, or is this principally impossible? I can put non-windowed aggregation into HAVING clause, why not windowed one? Also, could u check it in FB3 ?

Comment: I don't think cortege is an English word (or otherwise it is an obscure one), you might want to rephrase it. And yes, you need to wrap the query, the window function doesn't behave as a `group by`, so you can't access it in the `where` or `having` of the same query expression. I'd choose a different name than rank though, as rank is a different window function ;).

Comment: Well, it is used here in theoretical sources of RDBMS concept. Probably is of French origin. I don't know the native terminology used in English sources on RDBMS theory. /// I though about using different name, but is there is no clash happened in this context I left the easier to comprehend full word, rather then "rnk" or some other obscure abbreviation. /// frankly, I see `having` in a typical aggregating query as a post-filter that can only be applied when the aggregation was complete. And there seems to be no underlying difference with `partition by` WinFunc here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but there IS a way to do it without joins!

Comment: I'm not sure why you are addressing that comment to me.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thought you would find such a trick useful or at least funny. (It was not the mail list, it was a russian-language forum, where another novice came with similar question)

Comment: Here is the FB3 plan for the query: http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=1283351&msg=21133861 It shows only one scan was made, so on small to medium table it probably would be faster than join-based solution, and certainly has less copy-paste

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
select COD, ORDER, S.DATE, REVISION 
FROM TAB1
JOIN 
(
   select ORDER, MAX(REVISION) as REVISION
   FROM TAB1
   Group By ORDER
) m on m.ORDER = TAB1.ORDER and m.REVISION = TAB1.REVISION
```

Comment: Thanks. If  I have to join other tables, have I to use: "SELECT... FROM... GROUP.... and then LEFT OUTER JOIN... ORDER BY" etc?

Comment: Actually it would not work, since rows #2 and #3 have different DATE value. You have to put some totaling function over date and remove it from GROUP clause, if you can ignore the value in DATE. And exactly same u have to do with COD

Comment: This answer does not return two rows for the sample data.

Comment: And no again. This would  match ANY order from TAB1 with ANY order from M

Comment: Now, this 3rd version is kind of correct :-D  Except that `DATE` and `ORDER` are reserved SQL keywords and would not just work without escaping, but that is not your fault.

Comment: Thank you @Arioch'The for pointing out my errors. I wrote the query without creating a fiddle and didn't test it at first. I learned my lesson for next time. I also thought about the reserved word issue.

Comment: Frankly, queries like that boil down to that boring copy-paste of almost duplicating the query.... I wonder if "WINDOW FUNCTIONS" introduced in Firebird 3 could provide for making a query without joins. Most probably they would, but I do not quite understand those new functions. PS. actually the lesson would be more like "do not be hasty". I spotted those errors without and before the fiddle. They are typical when you try to hack keys fast - and keep forgetting boring details, in the end it makes things longer :-D

Comment: Yep, window functions can make the join-less query, though with some hassle... And I am not sure it would be faster on real data, as it may just ignore indexes on order+revision cortege and do a full-scan instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the max revision number in Firebird:

```
select t.*
from tab1 t
where t.revision = (select max(t2.revision) from tab1 t2 where t2.order = t.order);
```

For performance, you want an index on `tab1(order, revision)`.  With such an index, performance should be competitive with any other approach.

Comment: This would re-run the internal query for every single row in tab1. While correct data, the execution would be quite slow, if there are many revisions for most orders.

Comment: This would be an idea to try if there would be few extra filters on T that remove like 90% of rows before max-revision filter get applied, then it would make sense.

Comment: UPD. the said index would still require firebird to both natural-scan the T table and then locate and fetch the matching record for T2 table (for ever T's row). Surething, if the table is small it would all be loaded into RAM cache. Additionally, if there is only 2-3 revisions for every order, then natural-scan over whole T table might be faster than indexed fetch of 33%-50% of it. That depends on the specific data and when performance is paramount should be tested.