# Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause) with join

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird

The question I asked yesterday was simplified but I realize that I have to report the whole story. I have to extract the data of 4 from 4 different tables into a Firebird 2.5 database and the following query works:

```
SELECT 
PRODUZIONE_T t.CODPRODUZIONE, 
PRODUZIONE_T.NUMEROCOMMESSA as numeroco,
    ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.RAGIONESOCIALE1, 
    PRODUZIONE_T.DATACONSEGNA, 
    MAX(PRODUZIONE_T.REVISIONE),
    ANGUTENTI.NOMINATIVO, 
    ORDINI.T_DATA,
FROM PRODUZIONE_T
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDINI_T ON PRODUZIONE_T.CODORDINE=ORDINI_T.CODORDINE 
INNER JOIN ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI ON ANGCLIENTIFORNITORI.CODCLIFOR=ORDINI_T.CODCLIFOR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ANGUTENTI ON ANGUTENTI.IDUTENTE = PRODUZIONE_T.RESPONSABILEUC
GROUP BY produzione_t.numerocommessa
ORDER BY right(numeroco,2) DESC, left(numeroco,3) desc 
rows 1 to 500;
```

What I have to change? I want ONLY ONE ROWS FOR EVERY NUMEROCOMMESSA with has its max REVISIONE value.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY all selected columns, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: just add the same Windows Functions column and wrapper as in my 2nd answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324746/firebird-select-from-table-distinct-one-field

Comment: what is `PRIMARY KEY` on the `PRODUZIONE_T` table ? make one more, separate `SELECT` to fetch `max(revizione)` and joint it with your your "big" query over P.K. identity between both `PRODUZIONE_T` tables

Comment: PRIMARY KEY is CODORDINE

Comment: Cannot use ROW_NUMBER() etc...

Comment: in firebird 2.x you can not, but yesterday you tagged your question with firebird 3. // see my first answer then, you would have to use create similar construct and to join inner SELECT (getting max-revisions from PRODUZIONE_T) with an outer one (getting all needed data for the values reported by inner select)

Comment: Thanks @Arioch'The. Do you mean I have to create a new table? I have read-only access to this database.

Comment: I DID IT! Thanks a lot

Comment: you do not create new table, you do two queries to the same table and refer to them both by different `aliases`