# Error "cannot SELECT RDB$DB_KEY from stored procedure" in CTE query

Tags: sql, firebird, common-table-expression, firebird2.5

Running Firebird SQL 2.5.6

This works as expected:

```
select guarantor_id, guarantor_first, guarantor_last,  chart, patient_First, 
patient_last, pcp, copaybalance, status_pat, effective_dor, elapsed, case 
when elapsed <30 then '0-30' when elapsed <60 then '31-60' when elapsed <90 
then '61-90' when elapsed <120 then '91-120'  else '121+' end as bucket from
(

select guarantor_id, first_name as guarantor_first, last_name as 
guarantor_last, patno as chart, fname as patient_First, lname as 
patient_last, addr_id as pcp,  copaybalance, status_pat, effective_dor,
datediff(day, cast(effective_dor as date), cast('today' as date)) as elapsed
from
(

select at1.*, at2.date1 as dor, at2.cptcode as orig_cpt, case when at2.date1 
is null then at1.date1 else at2.date1 end as effective_dor, fname,lname, 
guarantor_id, register.addr_id, first_name, last_name, status_pat from
(select patno, invoiceno, trnsxno, date1, cptcode, copaybalance from 
archive_Transactions where archive_flag = 1 and cptcode not in 
('1','2','4','RETCHK') and copaybalance >= 0.01)  at1
left outer join (Select * from archive_transactions where archive_flag = 1 
and cptcode not in ('1','2')) at2 on at2.txnopaid = at1.trnsxno
inner join register on register.patno = at1.patno
inner join contact on contact.id = register.guarantor_id
order by patno
) 
)
```

Next, I wrapped that query into a CTE structure (to be used for further manipulation in a larger query):

```
with b as 
(

select guarantor_id, guarantor_first, guarantor_last,  chart, patient_First, 
patient_last, pcp, copaybalance, status_pat, effective_dor, elapsed, case 
when elapsed <30 then '0-30' when elapsed <60 then '31-60' when elapsed <90 
then '61-90' when elapsed <120 then '91-120'  else '121+' end as bucket from
(

select guarantor_id, first_name as guarantor_first, last_name as 
guarantor_last, patno as chart, fname as patient_First, lname as p 
patient_last, addr_id as pcp,  copaybalance, status_pat, effective_dor,
datediff(day, cast(effective_dor as date), cast('today' as date)) as elapsed
from
(

select at1.*, at2.date1 as dor, at2.cptcode as orig_cpt, case when at2.date1 
is null then at1.date1 else at2.date1 end as effective_dor, fname,lname, 
guarantor_id, register.addr_id, first_name, last_name, status_pat from
(select patno, invoiceno, trnsxno, date1, cptcode, copaybalance from 
archive_Transactions where archive_flag = 1 and cptcode not in 
('1','2','4','RETCHK') and copaybalance >= 0.01)  at1
left outer join (Select * from archive_transactions where archive_flag = 1 
and cptcode not in ('1','2')) at2 on at2.txnopaid = at1.trnsxno
inner join register on register.patno = at1.patno
inner join contact on contact.id = register.guarantor_id
order by patno
) 
)
)

select * from b
```

I would expect identical results.  Instead, I get an error message:

```
SQL error code = -607
Cannot SELECT RDB$DB_KEY from a stored procedure
SQL warning code =301
DATE date type is now called TIMESTAMP
SQL warning code = 301
DATE data type is now called TIMESTAMP
```

I'm able to run lots of other CTE-containing queries, many of which are more complex, like:

```
with myAging as 
(
select patno,fname,lname, sum(copaybalance) as pat_owed, min(e_dor) as 
eff_pat_dor, guarantor_id
from
(
select patno, fname,lname, trnsxno, date1, cptcode, copaybalance, 
max(effective_dor) as e_dor, guarantor_id from
(
select at1.*, at2.date1 as dor, at2.cptcode as orig_cpt, case when at2.date1 
is null then at1.date1 else at2.date1 end as effective_dor, fname,lname, 
guarantor_id from
(select patno, invoiceno, trnsxno, date1, cptcode, copaybalance from 
archive_Transactions where archive_flag = 1 and cptcode not in 
('1','2','4','RETCHK') and copaybalance >= 0.01)  at1
left outer join (Select * from archive_transactions where archive_flag = 1 
and cptcode not in ('1','2')) at2 on at2.txnopaid = at1.trnsxno
inner join register on register.patno = at1.patno
order by patno
)
group by patno, fname,lname, trnsxno, date1, cptcode, copaybalance, 
guarantor_id
) group by patno,fname,lname, guarantor_id
) 

select a.*, m.fam_dor, m2.fam_owed
from
(
select guarantor_id, guarantor, address_1, address_2, city, state, zip_code, 
patno, ma.fname,ma.lname,ma.pat_owed,ma.eff_pat_dor
from
(
select patno, ( first_name || case when middle_name = '' then ' ' when m 
middle_name is null then ' ' else (' ' || middle_name || ' ') end  ||  
last_name)
as guarantor,  contact.address_1, contact.address_2, contact.city, c 
contact.state, contact.zip_code, copaybal, guarantor_id from register 
inner join contact on contact.id = register.guarantor_id
where copaybal >= 0.01
 ) g
left outer join (select patno, fname, lname, pat_owed,eff_pat_dor from 
myAging) ma on ma.patno = g.patno


order by guarantor_id
) a
inner join
(select guarantor_id, min(eff_pat_dor) as fam_dor from myAging group by 
guarantor_id) m on m.guarantor_id = a.guarantor_id
inner join
(select guarantor_id, sum(pat_owed) as fam_owed from myAging group by 
guarantor_id) m2 on m2.guarantor_id = a.guarantor_id
```

...so this one must be fundamentally different somehow, but I don't see how.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Firebird 2.0? Common Table Expressions were introduced in Firebird 2.1. Please specify your full Firebird version. In any case, afaik the error indicates you are mixing SQL dialects (or maybe stored procedures or views created in a different dialect than your current dialect).

Comment: I would also suggest that you strip down your code to the bare minimum necessary to reproduce the problem, and then provide a [mcve] with all relevant DDL and sample data to reproduce.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are correct; a query of the ENGINE_VERSION returns 2.5.6. Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest to first upgrade to 2.5.8, and check if this might be a bug that has been fixed (although I don't see anything in the release notes that looks like this problem). Otherwise, reducing the code to the bare minimum necessary would be very helpful.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm not able to upgrade the engine; I'm an end user of this application, not the developer.

Comment: you are an "application end user" and you are writing SQL queries, not just use the application-provided ones o_O ?   Please look at how I was incrementally constructing a CTE here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398120/976391 and try to do the same with your query. Try to find the specific step, the specific sub-query adding which triggers the error. Then you would have to see what relation you added. For example it can be VIEW using a STORED PROCEDURE or something